# Embed Google Drawing Inside Google Docs

Tags: google-drive

Is there any way I can embed Google Drawing in a Google Doc?

The [suggestion here](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179708) doesn't seem to apply to a new version of Google Docs. First, it is not about embedding a drawing. Second, even though I can copy from Google Drawing, I can't paste it inside the Google Doc.

Answer (score 13):

There is a way to embed a google drawing on web or in another doc.

*On the **drawing** doc:*

1. Choose **Share** -> **Publish to the web...** from the top right.

Copy this url it gives you.

*Go to the **other doc** you want to embed it in:*

1. Insert -> Image
2. Paste the public image url you published to above.

It will now be linked and updated as a image when you update the original drawing.

Comment: although the drawing *does* appear in Google Docs, but the image is not updated when the original drawing is updated.

Comment: @Graviton - it updates, but not in real-time, e.g. the page with the image on it needs to be refreshed - because the image isn't polled for changes.  What will cause a change is when the viewer revisits the document or switches sheets in a spreadsheet.

Comment: I have done such an experiment, but the image in Google Docs doesn't seem to be working. Here are [the](https://docs.google.com/drawings/edit?id=1QF2JouvziCYaPCkERy5kld1No8NORf63O7XwKN22nXY&hl=en) [links](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=12wkpQaceF3R1OGR8qlelHtaCNz44KlA05sj--ZxBJWU). You can verify that the drawing and the docs are out of synch.

Comment: @Graviton, I have opened both the docs you linked to and they look exactly the same in sync.  Perhaps you're on a network that caches more heavily - try Ctrl-F5?  But this definitely works.

Comment: Note, this does NOT work if the Google Drawing is marked as "Require viewers to sign in with their XXX account".  I'm using this for work and can't mark everything public.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my document, I can download the image by putting in the URL but it doesn't seem to allow me to insert the image into a document

Comment: Didn't work for me either.

Comment: Looks like the current version of Docs does not refresh images. I published a drawing and inserted into my document but when I modify the drawing, changes are not updated. I tried refreshing page, using different browser. Then must be cached by docs.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me... see [here](http://docs.google.com/View?id=dfrgr4zf_27hsd2vthz)... so I think the questions should maybe be why can't I embed a Google Drawing in a Google Doc when other people can? In that case, I don't know... perhaps you had Gears enabled and that's now causing a problem... perhaps you're still somehow using the old version?

Comment: are you enabling a new version of Google Docs? Also, what browser you use? I use google chrome

Comment: Hrm, in Spreadsheets, I have the option to switch back to the old one, but in a Document I don't have that option... maybe I'm still on the old version for some reason - I thought it had been rolled out to everyone now. I'm in Chrome too BTW.

Comment: The link in your reply is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can get something to work is exporting the drawing to a PNG file locally and then importing it into Docs. You will need to crop the image to make it look good. If you update the drawing, you need to redo the procedure.

It appears that the SVG vector graphics format that Drawings can export to isn't supported by Docs.